# Get a parameter value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cognos, cognos-8

In Cognos 8.4, I have a prompt, **"NAME"**, and its parameter p_name.

How do I get that parameter through JavaScript?

```
<script>
    alert(p_name)
</script>
```

shows a JavaScript error. Why?

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the reference for the object will be missing, and you have to keep up with the scope of the variables or the parameters. You can use the "**Developer Tools**" in Internet Explorer 8 by pressing "**f12**". There in the right hand side pan you can choose the tab "**console**" to find where you went wrong or you can choose the tab "**locals**" to find whether the parameter has any values in the scope where you are calling it.

Comment: But Still how could this help me in cognos? I guess you are giving me solution regd purely Javascript? do you have any idea related to cognos as well?

Comment: As you sair i checked in locals. By default its empty? Do i need to click any to find specific paramenter?

Comment: Please can u paste the actual part of the code u r trying to work on? But i don't know cognos. This is a javascript part so I think I can help u out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Cognos, but your problem is that you are calling a variable that is local to an object in the global scope. You have to do `whatEverTheObjectIsCalled.p_name` (probably). An easy way to find out exactly what you are looking for is to fire up the web page in Chrome and `console.log(theObject)` and browse through the internals of the object until you find the attribute you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply James. 
Sorry we dont have access to chrome in office. Do you have any thing similar to console.log(theObject) in Internet Exlporer 8?